# how do i copyright my book? please help thanks

Tags: copyright

i'm ready to go to copyright but the gov.copyright page is to confusing help please thought I knew what to do but now lost. thanks

Comment: Can you explain what you don't understand about what you've researched? It's all there on Google, we just need to know what you are having trouble with understanding.

Comment: Hmm, the referenced duplicate question specifically refers to an e-book, while this question just says a book in general. Saying that this is a duplicate embodies the assumption that the process is exactly the same. Which it is not. For starters, copyrighting a paper book requires mailing two physical copies to the copyright office, which at the least requires additional explanation for an e-book. And anyone asking presumably does not know how similar or different the procedures are. Etc.

Comment: One thing to consider is that full copyright (depending on a countries copyright law) may not take effect (or be otherwise modified) until a work is "published" e.g. offered to the general public. For ebooks, simply adding a link to it on a publicly available website should count as "publishing" in most instances.

Comment: Note that for the United States specifically, "No publication or registration or other action in the [U.S.] Copyright Office is required to secure copyright. [...] Copyright is secured automatically when the work is cre­ated, and a work is “created” when it is fixed in a copy or 
phonorecord for the first time. “Copies” are material objects 
from which a work can be read or visually perceived either 
directly or with the aid of a machine or device, such as books, 
manuscripts, sheet music, film, videotape, or microfilm. "  - http://www.copyright.gov/circs/circ01.pdf

Answer (score -1):

http://copyrightregistry-online-form.com/?gclid=Cj0KEQjwzq63BRCrtIuGjImRoIIBEiQAGLHdYSgKm6Z75J4lJjVTdOJyskYRX0mgdb2dWZCE7L1LET8aAlcW8P8HAQ easy to follow and in most cases instant.